# Is it possible to test IE6 with Selenium2 and how to use "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have this problem with testing IE6 with Selenium2. I use Perl bindings ([Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/module/Selenium%3a%3aRemote%3a%3aDriver))  but  I will greatly appreciate any suggestions, even if they will be from people who have experience with Selenium for Java etc.

The problem is that when I try to do this:

```
my %opt = (
   browser_name    => 'internet explorer',
   version         => '6',
   platform        => 'WINDOWS',
   proxy           => {
       proxyType => 'direct',
   }
);
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(%opt);
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
my $elem = $driver->find_element('gs_htif0', 'id');
$elem->send_keys('fooooooo');
```

The browser opens, but then the test dies with the message `An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters: gs_htif0,id at ...`, while in IE7 all works fine, and the documentation to IE driver says that IE6 was tested

After that I tried to start a node with `"seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"`, which I thought was the option for testing any browser for which there is no driver, so it could be tested in the old way of "JavaScript emulation" of users actions, but then browser did not start at all, test died with the message `java.lang.NullPointerException: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?`

My hub-config is:

```
{
    "host": null,
    "port": 4444,
    "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
    "servlets" : [],
    "prioritizer": null,
    "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
    "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
    "nodePolling": 5000,

    "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
    "timeout": 300000,
    "browserTimeout": 0,
"maxSession": 5
}
```

My node-config is:

```
{
    "capabilities":
    [
        {
            "platform": "WINDOWS",
            "browserName": "internet explorer",
            "version": "6",
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
            "ensureCleanSession": true
        }
    ],
    "configuration":
    {
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "maxSession": 1,
        "port": 5555,
        "host": "192.168.1.6",
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "hubHost": "192.168.1.34"
    }
}
```

start node command is `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig node_ie6_conf.json -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="IEDriverServer_2.29x32.exe" > nul`

Start hub command is `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub_conf.json &> dev/null`

Can anyone assist me with this? My appreciation.

---

**Update**
For the second part of my question I suppose that Selenium::Remote::Driver works only with webDriver protocol, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of my question the answer is "yes, it is possible". Assuming a one has properly set hub, node and [InternetExplorerDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver), she only needs to configure security settings in the "security" tab in the IE settings window (open service -> internet options). And there she must move slider one point down to set "medium" level for the "local intranet".

Sorry for the screenshot being not in English, but I do not have English XP, I suppose it is clear where to find this:

[image]

I found the answer unexpectedly, after I started to experience the same issue in IE7, immediately after I've changed security settings, so it hinted me where to seek.

But the second part `how to use "selenium protocol"` still remains unresolved.